# git fetch: "inflate: data stream error" e "SHA1 COLLISION FOUND WITH"

Tags: git

Eu tenho na minha máquina uma cópia do repositório para trabalho, outra para manutenção e uma terceira só para resolver conflitos de *merge request*. O repositório externo fica no https://gitlab.com

Na cópia de resolução de conflitos, obtive o seguinte ao dar um `git fetch`:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 4339, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2008/2008), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack e68ba06d6fc973e561ea7663cd46a6563e4db00a header
fatal: SHA1 COLLISION FOUND WITH e68ba06d6fc973e561ea7663cd46a6563e4db00a !
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Alguém já passou por esse problema de `SHA1 COLLISION FOUND`? Rodar um GC mais agressivo resolve? Ou eu devo dar um *fetch **forçado*** (se é que isso existe)? E por que eu obtenho esse erro de *inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)*?

Nas minha outras duas cópias o `git fetch` simplesmente funciona.

---

Segui a dica do [@Wéllingthon M. de Souza](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/60376/w%c3%a9llingthon-m-de-souza) e fui atrás das respostas a [essa pergunta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/801577/4438007).

Tentei seguir as duas respostas com maior pontuação agora ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802297/4438007) e [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/820167/4438007)).

A primeira coisa que fiz foi seguir como a pergunta, `fsck`:

```
$ git fsck --full
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack 0df41c704c7ab987a2a87f5487ba94b11fee5651 header
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: loose object 0df41c704c7ab987a2a87f5487ba94b11fee5651 (stored in .git/objects/0d/f41c704c7ab987a2a87f5487ba94b11fee5651) is corrupt
```

Não consegui nem seguir os primeiros passos das soluções, que envolvem mover os arquivos armazenados em `.git/objects/pack`:

```
$ mv ../.git/objects/pack/* ./
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-2ef12a374f233953f4fd8a15aa389cd156ee21ab.pack’ to ‘./pack-2ef12a374f233953f4fd8a15aa389cd156ee21ab.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-31eb069000dfed9dc33627cf36ee2197458ad82e.pack’ to ‘./pack-31eb069000dfed9dc33627cf36ee2197458ad82e.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-3b3cf3cbadf5413a348678edcd3ad5aae1dc2c16.pack’ to ‘./pack-3b3cf3cbadf5413a348678edcd3ad5aae1dc2c16.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-635a59f8711f44b67a4507a411a0a0c0285c0ca7.pack’ to ‘./pack-635a59f8711f44b67a4507a411a0a0c0285c0ca7.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-6886cb0119bfd4643b98c4f501f10e629ab74e9c.pack’ to ‘./pack-6886cb0119bfd4643b98c4f501f10e629ab74e9c.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-6e052067c769830ca129a0e8c7bfc4d44764fe15.pack’ to ‘./pack-6e052067c769830ca129a0e8c7bfc4d44764fe15.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-752d7c35962f8a2ea4e822513fb2c556905c00d7.pack’ to ‘./pack-752d7c35962f8a2ea4e822513fb2c556905c00d7.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-7f33b3a5474a3e1e6fe6aaa803b6350d2e042eb4.pack’ to ‘./pack-7f33b3a5474a3e1e6fe6aaa803b6350d2e042eb4.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-a80982d4620dd4cef6f81e3be901cae4c69fde35.pack’ to ‘./pack-a80982d4620dd4cef6f81e3be901cae4c69fde35.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-b434b91b1a0a7320412e2cbca96037f8299ef2ac.pack’ to ‘./pack-b434b91b1a0a7320412e2cbca96037f8299ef2ac.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-ba586b682318e5d28720392029682881c15a94bc.pack’ to ‘./pack-ba586b682318e5d28720392029682881c15a94bc.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-bbf1e8e462d030724464eda227311152a1514afd.pack’ to ‘./pack-bbf1e8e462d030724464eda227311152a1514afd.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-c01218c7abd55796907a9d3bc495a181bde71eaf.pack’ to ‘./pack-c01218c7abd55796907a9d3bc495a181bde71eaf.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-c1a7902d592bd9fd1aea549bbd005caaffbee33f.pack’ to ‘./pack-c1a7902d592bd9fd1aea549bbd005caaffbee33f.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-c91ad861113299d4dab0881b1d6486f30e9bf1b4.pack’ to ‘./pack-c91ad861113299d4dab0881b1d6486f30e9bf1b4.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-d48093c898ed05e058c3a9c892ec0609069ad60d.pack’ to ‘./pack-d48093c898ed05e058c3a9c892ec0609069ad60d.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-da0630673a62d977df8ffbbc50fd61df1569e6a3.pack’ to ‘./pack-da0630673a62d977df8ffbbc50fd61df1569e6a3.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/pack-eda963306885c442497749083b08dc217a91567a.pack’ to ‘./pack-eda963306885c442497749083b08dc217a91567a.pack’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘../.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_TnUODc’ to ‘./tmp_pack_TnUODc’: Device or resource busy
```

Eu tentei simplesmente copiar os arquivos, o que deu certo, e então chamar o `git unpack-objects -r` para cada arquivo copiado. Demorou um certo tempo, mas o `git` retornou dizendo que foi um sucesso. Porém, rodar `git fsck` continua dando o mesmo erro.

Também não consigo rodar um  `git gc`...

```
$ git gc
error: bad ref for refs/remotes/origin/hotfix-{nome-do-branch 3}
error: refs/remotes/interno/feateure-{nome do branch 2} does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/interno/rc-4.12 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/origin/feateure-{nome do branch 2} does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/origin/feature-{nome do branch 1} does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/remotes/origin/rc-4.12 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v4.12.0 does not point to a valid object!
error: refs/tags/v4.12.0-RC5 does not point to a valid object!
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 265cde674ee719afc8b113702111a2daff917bf4
error: Could not read 9949bd269ca9a170d63bb7a966f61f0ba2fa8bbf
error: Could not read a3c9b85a5edbafcb21b9bc545235563696e9b0a7
error: Could not read dd0511454dbb98fe63245c8b892e6f0598896ed7
error: Could not read 7dc587d4ac10c48d3b104c32eb3a5c6b46d2c3d3
error: Could not read d44b9b39c8a1780debb2e4eaebfe3183eda5822d
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+17 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+5 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+3 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+8 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 9949bd269ca9a170d63bb7a966f61f0ba2fa8bbf
(+1 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read a3c9b85a5edbafcb21b9bc545235563696e9b0a7
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dd0511454dbb98fe63245c8b892e6f0598896ed7
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 7dc587d4ac10c48d3b104c32eb3a5c6b46d2c3d3
(+1 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 7dc587d4ac10c48d3b104c32eb3a5c6b46d2c3d3
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 7dc587d4ac10c48d3b104c32eb3a5c6b46d2c3d3
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+29 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read d44b9b39c8a1780debb2e4eaebfe3183eda5822d
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+86 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+6 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+9 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read d44b9b39c8a1780debb2e4eaebfe3183eda5822d
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+5 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dd0511454dbb98fe63245c8b892e6f0598896ed7
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+8 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 9949bd269ca9a170d63bb7a966f61f0ba2fa8bbf
(+1 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read a3c9b85a5edbafcb21b9bc545235563696e9b0a7
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dd0511454dbb98fe63245c8b892e6f0598896ed7
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 7dc587d4ac10c48d3b104c32eb3a5c6b46d2c3d3
(+1 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 7dc587d4ac10c48d3b104c32eb3a5c6b46d2c3d3
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 7dc587d4ac10c48d3b104c32eb3a5c6b46d2c3d3
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read 4399cd6fbed8a44b269a60b63abf1dcd599312ad
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+4 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dbbfbdf73be8a9f38e26b85e74db1847cfd05bf4
(+2 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read dd0511454dbb98fe63245c8b892e6f0598896ed7
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+33 linhas idênticas)
error: Could not read d44b9b39c8a1780debb2e4eaebfe3183eda5822d
error: Could not read 25085f5de31daf24cb5313259f4a8141377b8f92
(+19 linhas idênticas)
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/interno/feateure-{nome-branch-4}
error: failed to run repack
```

Comment: Você já viu essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802297/83531540) lá no *SOen* ? Talvez ajude a resolver o problema

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza vou dar uma olhada, não tinha chegado aí ainda

Comment: Já conseguiu resolver o problema ? Tem essa outra [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964033) lá no *SOen*.

Comment: Você fez alguma coisa fora do comum no seu repositório antes de ter este erro?

Comment: Não que eu esteja ciente. Mas estava com o SourceTree e o Eclipse abertos. E eu sei que o Eclipse tem o `egit` dele que vira e mexe faz umas besteiras, enquanto que o SourceTree fica tentando pegar as informações do remoto de quando em sempre

Comment: @wmsouza, tive um problema semelhante hoje mesmo. Resolvi ler com calma a resposta que remove uma das referências ([esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28373010/4438007)) e funcionou. Vou ver se repetindo o mesmo feito no repositório que deu o bug original eu consigo sanar também

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei recuperar o repositório que havia dado problema na época da abertura do chamado. Acabou que eu havia alterado ele um pouco, mas eu fiz um backup depois de algumas tentativas para tentar estudar o problema.

Eis que boa parte dos erros inicialmente reportados continuam acontecendo:

```
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 84379, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (32363/32363), done.
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack e68ba06d6fc973e561ea7663cd46a6563e4db00a header
fatal: cannot read existing object info e68ba06d6fc973e561ea7663cd46a6563e4db00a
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Não tem mais o problema de `SHA1 COLLISION FOUND WITH`, entretanto.

A primeira coisa que fiz foi fechar todo e qualquer aplicativo que pudesse exigir bloqueio de qualquer objeto git (como o Eclipse ou o SourceTree).

Em seguida, tentei coletar lixo:

```
$ git gc --aggressive
error: bad ref for .git/logs/refs/remotes/origin/hotfix-{branch-1}
fatal: bad object refs/remotes/origin/hotfix-{branch-1}
error: failed to run repack
```

Sem GC, tentei fazer umas podas na árvore, mas também sem sucesso:

```
$ git prune
fatal: unable to parse object: refs/remotes/origin/hotfix-{branch-1}
```

Sem mais alternativas em vista para tentar resolver via git puro, resolvi remover a referência quebrada e ver se consiga dar um `prune`:

```
$ rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/hotfix-{branch-1}
$ git prune
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
error: unable to unpack e68ba06d6fc973e561ea7663cd46a6563e4db00a header
fatal: loose object e68ba06d6fc973e561ea7663cd46a6563e4db00a (stored in .git/objects/e6/8ba06d6fc973e561ea7663cd46a6563e4db00a) is corrupt
```

Hmmm, e que tal GC?

```
$ git gc --aggressive
Counting objects: 288960, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (222462/222462), done.
Writing objects: 100% (288960/288960), done.
Total 288960 (delta 122354), reused 164323 (delta 0)
Checking connectivity: 288960, done.
$ git prune
Checking connectivity: 288960, done.
```

Checando o `fsck` para ver se está tudo bem...

```
$ git fsck --full
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (288960/288960), done.
```

Confirmando que está de volta ao equilíbrio pegando as coisas do remoto...

```
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 84486, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (32403/32403), done.
remote: Total 84486 (delta 32338), reused 81967 (delta 31026)
Receiving objects: 100% (84486/84486), 14.67 MiB | 563.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (32338/32338), done.

From {endereço do origin}
 * [new branch]            {branch}            -> origin/{branch}
[... diversos outros branches e tags que entraram no projeto depois de 6 meses ...]
```

Então, sucesso.

> Agradeço especialmente ao @wmsouza por ter dado diversas referências que, durante esse tempo, serviram para que eu pudesse entender o que estava acontecendo e, finalmente, conseguir me recuperar do problema de maneira elegante

### Recapitulando

1. remoção das **referências** corrompidas:

   ```
   $ rm rm .git/refs/remotes/origin/hotfix-{branch-1}
   ```
2. coleta de lixo/*garbage collector* agressivo para coletar todos os **objetos** corrompidos:

   ```
   $ git gc --aggressive
   ```
3. verificar se está tudo funcional, por via das dúvidas?

   ```
   $ git fsck --full
   ```